# - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~2.1.0 Error After Installing Expo SDK 44

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

After A fresh Install of a new expo app which comes with Expo 44, I am receiving this error after trying to install reanimated.
The error appears in the terminal after running ***npm start***

kindly assist

The error is as follows:

````
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~2.1.0 - actual version installed: 2.2.0```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error i was getting i did run the following command and it got fixed automatically by expo doctor

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```